# VBA Loop for and do while

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, do-while

I am trying to create a For and Do while loop in VBA. I want that when the value 'X' is entered in column A and if column W is equal to "T", all the rows below (column A) should be checked "X" until the next value "T" in column W.
My script does not work, only the row below is filled with "X" and the file closes (bug!)

Here is the complete code

```
Sub Chaine()
  
    For Each Cell In Range("A2:A3558")
        If UCase(Cell.Value) = "X" And Cells(Target.Row, 23) = "T" Then
            Do While Cell.Offset(0, 23) <> "T"
            Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "X"
            Loop
        End If
    
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Would really help to show the complete code.  It looks like you're doing this in an event handler (because of `Target`) but there's some context missing here...

Comment: I’have changed and put the complete code

Comment: If this code is being called every time a cell on a worksheet is changed this will produce runaway recursion in excel. Where is this being called from?

Comment: That code has no declaration for `Target` ?   What is that?

Comment: What does _does not work_ mean? It errors? Nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Chaine()
    Dim c As Range, vW, flag As Boolean
    
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A3558").Cells
        vW = UCase(c.EntireRow.Columns("W").value)
        If UCase(c.value) = "X" And vW = "T" Then
            flag = True 'insert "X" beginning on next row...
        Else
            If vW = "T" Then flag = False  'stop adding "X"
            If flag Then c.value = "X"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work either. But thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your `Do While` loop has to be problem as it doesn't change and will continue to check the same thing. It's unclear what you want to happen, but consider something like this as it moves to the right until you've exceeded the `usedrange`.

```
Sub Chaine()
Dim cell As Range

      For Each cell In Range("A2:A3558").Cells
        If UCase(cell.Value) = "X" And Cells(Target.Row, 23) = "T" Then
            Do While cell.Offset(0, 23) <> "T"
               Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
               'not sure what this is supposed to do...?
               'cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "X"
               
               If cell.Column > cell.Worksheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, cell.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column Then
                  MsgBox "This has gone too far left..."
                  Stop
               End If
               
               
            Loop
        End If
    
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't work. But thank you for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

I just went off your description in the question. Your code is not doing what you want and it's not really how you would do this in my opinion. I figured I would put an answer that does what you ask but, keep it simple.

I'm guessing Target in the code refers to an event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo SomethingBadHappened
'Checks if you are in the A column from the target cell that 
'was changed and checks if only X was typed.
    If (Target.Column = 1 And UCase(Target) = "X") Then
        Dim colToCheck_Index As Integer
        colToCheck_Index = 23 'W Column
        Dim colToCheck_Value As String
        Dim curRow_Index As Integer
        curRow_Index = Target.Cells.Row
'Checks if the column we are checking has only a T as the value.
        If (UCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow_Index, colToCheck_Index).Value) = "T") Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Do
'Set the proper cell to X
                Range("A" & curRow_Index).Value = "X"
                curRow_Index = curRow_Index + 1
'Set the checking value to the next row and check it in the 
'while loop if it doesn't equal only T
                colToCheck_Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow_Index, colToCheck_Index)
'Set the last row to X on the A column.
            Loop While UCase(colToCheck_Value) <> "T"
            Range("A" & curRow_Index).Value = "X"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
Exit Sub
SomethingBadHappened:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you it works! the rows are well filled with the X. but on the other hand, the line there is a "T" also with X (only the first one after the series).

Comment: @Joanne No problem! The row curRow_Index determines what row/line you are on and start on so if you start it on the line underneath the current row or Target.Cells.Row+1 That should do it.